# Is there a Bing Shopping API?

Tags: azure, bing-api

I tried searching MS azure market to find bing shopping api access and don't seem to find it, is there any or there's no api access to bing shopping ?

Thanks,
Mika

Answer (score 2):

Bing Shooping API is directly maintained & supported through shopping.com not however still not part of Windows Azure Data Market as described in **[this](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/search-advertising/bing-shopping)** article.

Please download Bing Shopping Merchant Integration Guide from [**here**](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/WWDocs/User/smb/en-us/BeyondSearch/Bing_Shopping_Integration_Guide.pdf) and you will learn how to integrate in in your application as this provides step by step details on how to use Bing Shopping.

If you have any question on using Bing shopping, please visit [**Bing Shopping Forum page**](http://community.bingads.microsoft.com/ads/en/api/f/31/t/68940.aspx) and submit your questions to get direct assistance.